# Error installing Grails with GVM - Curl issue

Tags: grails, gvm

I am having trouble installing Grails via GVM. I installed GVM via the instructions on [GVM's website](http://gvmtool.net/), and it appears it was installed correctly - restarting the terminal and running `gvm help` produces a list of possible commands. However, when I go to install Grails (or Groovy), I get the following output in the terminal:

```
$ gvm install grails

Downloading: grails 2.3.2

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (1) Protocol [http not supported or disabled in libcurl
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /Users/neilpoulin/.gvm/archives/grails-    2.3.2.zip or
        /Users/neilpoulin/.gvm/archives/grails-2.3.2.zip.zip, and cannot find     /Users/neilpoulin/.gvm/archives/grails-2.3.2.zip.ZIP, period.

Stop! The archive was corrupt and has been removed! Please try installing again.
```

I looked to make sure zip, unzip and curl were found:

```
    $ which zip
    /usr/bin/zip

    $ which unzip
    /usr/bin/unzip

    $ which curl
    /usr/bin/curl
```

Prior to this, the only thing I have done with Grails/Groovy is to execute the example project include on the Grails website - http://grails.org/learn > step 2.

What am I missing here? is there some configuration of `libcurl` I need to change? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I think that is happening for everyone.  It's happened before.  Something to do with the servers, not gvm specifically.  It's happening to me tonight as well.

Comment: First time gvm user, setting up on my new macbook pro, and I get the same exact issue for any gvm install I try.  I did notice that the "Protocol [http..." seems to have a bracket before the http where it might not.  The curl docs indicate that if the protocol is malformed, this error would result.  Maybe someone left an extra square bracket in the curl command?

Comment: Similar or same issue in nabble: http://forum.gvmtool.net/Grails-install-is-failing-due-to-incorrect-redirect-URL-td77.html

Comment: According to the gvmtool user on twitter,  this should be fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On investigation, it seems to be down to inconsistent versions (and behaviour) of MongoDB between our dev and prod environments. This was resulting in our prod server returning an array of urls on the download request (ie [theurl]). This was working perfectly on our dev environment, but started serving the array when the release was promoted to prod. Hope this is making sense!

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem persist— for me, it turned out that there were corrupt candidates caches by gvm during a previously failed install.

```
gvm flush candidates
```

set things back to rights, here.